# Defining which network to use for SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

This may turn out to be a very easy solution, but I am having an issue connecting to a local PC's database. Specifically, I need PC #1 to connect to PC #2's database through the use of the SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.

The problem arises in that PC #1 is connected to 2 simultaneous networks - one to the internet, and the other directly wired via Ethernet to PC #2. This causes PC #1 to fail in connecting to PC #2, because I assume that PC #1 is trying to connect to PC #2's IP address through the wrong network (the one to the internet) rather than the right one (the direct connection). If I unplug its connection to the internet, then the connection works just fine, since there is only one network to choose from.

So the question is simple: how do I define which network to prefer to use while connecting to a server using the SQL Server 2012 Management Studio?

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the server name rather than IP? Have you been using a local ip address to connect e.g. 10.10.xx.xx?

Comment: The SQL Server Management Studio does not seem to give an actual IP address to connect to. It only allows me to connect to the server name.

Comment: Just go on the server, run an ipconfig ans see the address.

Comment: Find out the local ip address of the PC / Server it is on then connect to it with that and its name e.g. 10.x.x.x\SQLServerName

Comment: I did not know that I could connect by typing just the IP address rather than the server name. Thank you very much. That solved my problem.